# Defining a Node in a class and outside of class

Tags: c++, object-oriented-analysis

How can the difference between Header-File-1 and Header-File-2 affect the program (which is written in C++)?

Which one is the better practice for coding?

Thank you for your responses in advance.

Header-File-1

```
#ifndef BST 
#define BST

#include<cstdlib>

class BST{

struct Node{

    DataType dataIn;
    Node * rigth;
    Node * left;
};
     public:
         BST();
        ~BST();
         Node * insert(DataType dataIn);
         Node * remove(DataType dataOut);
         Node * search(DataType dataSearch);
         void printTree();
     private:
         Node * root;
} 
#endif
```

Header-File-2

```
#ifndef BST 
#define BST

#include<cstdlib>

struct Node{

    DataType dataIn;
    Node * rigth;
    Node * left;
};

class BST{
     public:
         BST();
        ~BST();
         Node * insert(DataType dataIn);
         Node * remove(DataType dataOut);
         Node * search(DataType dataSearch);
         void printTree();
     private:
         Node * root;
} 
#endif
```

Comment: `using namespace std;` is always bad

Comment: And *"Which one is the better practice for coding?"* is opinion-based, they both could have potential use-cases

Comment: if you make the definition of  `Node` public in header1, then there is little difference. If it is private it will be difficult for users of `BST` to use the pointers returned from your methods

Comment: @UnholySheep "using namespace std; is always bad ". In general or in the header file?

Comment: Don't complicate things up. Write an easy and readable code. In my opinion Use `clsss Node` out side `class BST` that is some day maybe you need another sort of `trees` then you you can use the  `class Node` you decared outside.

Comment: Unrelated, I'd spend equatable time pondering the public-facing `insert`, `remove`, and `search` functions, all of which expect a `root` as the first argument, where the only initial root they conceptual should use on initial entry from an external call (assuming they're recursive) is already provided by the private `root` member variable. In short, those parameters shouldn't be needed in the public-facing member functions. That design problem is present in *both* headers.

Comment: Putting it in a header is *always* a bad idea, in a .cpp file it's debatable, but I'd avoid it - see here for a more detailed discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first header `struct Node` is private to the class, while in the second header it is a public top-level `struct`.

This means that `Node` of the first header is useless: if you were to write something like this

```
BST::Node *n = bst.search(nullptr, DataType());
```

the code would not compile:

> error: `struct BST::Node` is private within this context

Making `struct Node` public would fix this problem. This would be a slight improvement on the second header, because it would demonstrate closeness of `Node` to `BST`.

However, this is not ideal, because `Node` is still exposed to the outside of `BST`. This is sub-optimal, because the implementation details are visible to the outside of the class. A better approach would be to make `Node` private in the `BST` class, and change the API in such a way that `Node` is never accessed from outside the `BST`. This can be achieved by using the `root` instance variable of the `BST` class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  You mean I should not return Node * at all since a user can reach the three. Then I can only return true and false. Am I correct?

Comment: @grahamScan You could return a public iterator class, or follow the pattern used in `std::map` and return a pair that indicates what happened on insertion, and gives you an additional info in case that something has been replaced. Similarly, you could return the old value on remove, etc.

Comment: Can you give me an example that uses public iterator class? I am not able to find it. When I put Node definition inside of the class, I got error: unknown type name 'Node'.

Answer (score 1):

If your program use only one single sort of trees (in your case: BST) then it is the same in both cases; either declare it inside the class `BST` or outside and use containment.

- If your program deals with different kinds of trees then you should declare it outside the BST to be re-usable eg:

  ```
  struct Node{
      DataType dataIn;
      Node * rigth;
      Node * left;
  };

  class rootedBT {
      public:

      private:
         Node* R;
         Node* L;
         T data;
  };

  class fullBT {
      public:

      private:
         Node* R;
         Node* L;
         T data;
   };
  ```
- Also using `using namespace std` in headers is really horrible thing.
- Member data of a class are by default `private` so your `class Node` is private by default on contrary to a `struct`.